# Laravel : Eloquent Daily and monthly report

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have the following code to fetch the records :

`App\User::orderBy('balance', 'DESC')->limit(3)->get();`

How can i get the records for today, Last week and last month ?

I was adding `DB::raw('MONTH(created_at)', '=', date('m'))` but had no good !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle dates really nicely using **Carbon**, it's built into **laravel** so here's a few examples how we can make use of it.

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
```

Maybe date will equal something like this:

```
//one day (today)
$date = Carbon::now()->startOfDay;

//one month / 30 days
$date = Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->startOfDay;

App\User::where('field_name', '>=', $date)->orderBy('field_name', 'desc')->limit(3)->get();
```

You can see the full carbon docs over at http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

Good luck!

Comment: How can i use it with my above query ! In the question . It have `orderBy()`

Comment: You may also consider [query scopes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent#local-scopes), that'll make the code in this even cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

To do so better to create scopes in your model, example for Last week:

```
public function scopeLastWeek($query)
{
    return $query->where($query->created_at->diffInDays($query->created_at->copy()->addWeek()));
}
```

Then use it in your controller like this:

```
App\User::LastWeek()->orderBy('balance', 'DESC')->limit(3)->get();
```

Let me know if it is working..